# Using numpy reshape and the "array must be unchanged" error

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am receiving the error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

And I cannot seem to figure out how my array is being changed to throw this error, and pointing to the last line:

```
      1 data = hourlyElectricityForVisualization.values
----> 2 data = data.reshape((len(data)/24/7),24*7))
```

Note that:

```
data.shape = (2137,)
len(data) = 2137
```

My code that precipitates this error is as follows:

```
hourlyElectricity = pd.read_excel('D:/hourlyElectricity.xlsx')

index = (hourlyElectricity['startTime'] >= np.datetime64('2016-01-01')) & (hourlyElectricity['startTime'] < np.datetime64('2016-03-31'))
hourlyElectricityForVisualization = hourlyElectricity.loc[index,'electricity-kWh']

print ("Data length: ", len(hourlyElectricityForVisualization)/24/7, " weeks")
data = hourlyElectricityForVisualization.values
data = data.reshape((len(data)/24/7,24*7)
```

It is difficult for me to supply a dataset; so any suggestions without my inclusion of data are greatly appreciated!

Comment: 2137 is not divisible by 24*7 so this reshape operation doesn't make sense.

Comment: (with integer division, 2137/24/7*24*7 = 2016)

Comment: @Julien Could I try using the `math.ceil`  operator to make the math work out?

Comment: Nope, it's like wanting to reshape a 30 element vector into a n*7 matrix. 30 is not divisible by 7 so it doesn't make sense. Unless you ditch some elements (like the last 2 to get 28 which is 4*7) or pad with extra values (like adding five 0's to get 35 elements which is 5*7), in any case you'll need to modify the number of elements of your original array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete some data points to make it possible to fit into new matrix of size N-to-24*7. You can do the following:

`data = data[:(np.shape(data)[0] - np.shape(data)[0]%(24*7))]
data = np.reshape(data, (len(data)/24/7, 24*7))`

This code will delete last 121 points to make result of division of length of data to (24*7) integer.